# Sniff network traffic with scapy and regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, tcp, python-requests, scapy

I had my first glance on python's scapy package and wanted to test my first little script. In order to test the code below I sent myself an E-Mail containing this string "10000000000000". My expectation was that below minimal example (with my network card in monitoring mode and execution as su) would give an command line output for that E-Mail specifically but it doesn't. I am sure that this is caused by an misunderstanding of network traffic and tcp by myself -- could anyone elucidate?

The virtual environment I set-up is Python 3.6.8

(I have tested that I can sniff network traffic in general using the commented out line, only when I try to filter their content via regular expressions the result is not as I expected.)

```
import optparse

import scapy.all as sca
import re

from scapy import packet
from scapy.layers.dns import DNS
from scapy.layers.dot11 import Dot11Beacon, Dot11ProbeReq
from scapy.layers.inet import TCP


class SniffDataTraffic:
    @staticmethod
    def find_expr(pack: packet) -> str:
        regex_dict = {'foo': r"1[0-9]{13}",'bar': r"2[1-5]{14}"}
        raw_pack = pack.sprintf('%Raw.load%')
        found = {iter: re.findall(regex_dict[iter], raw_pack) for iter in regex_dict.keys()}

        for name, value in found.items():
            if value:
                return "[+] found {}: {}".format(name, value[0])


def main():
    try:
        print("[*] Starting sniffer")
        #sca.sniff(iface="xxxxxmon", prn=lambda x: x.summary(), store=False)
        sca.sniff(prn=SniffDataTraffic.find_expr, filter='tcp', iface="xxxxxmon", store=False)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Does the whole thing fail ? Try the old fashioned way of butchering your code into discrete pieces that can be tested separately.

Comment: You should also try with wireshark first before creating the Scapy script. Check that the packet actually has the string you are looking for in it's raw format, and that it's not encoded or anything. You are trying your regex on the raw layer. If the message was encrypted, compressed or just encoded, it might not appear as such.